# How to attach multiple images dynamically in Laravel-Slack Webhook?

Tags: laravel, for-loop, foreach, slack, slack-api

I am trying to post multiple images in a Slack Notification. It allows if I add "attachment" manually But I want to add attachments dynamically i.e. using a loop.

The following code works for manual attachments:

```
return (new SlackMessage)->attachment(function (SlackAttachment $attachment) {
                           $attachment->title('Title1')
                                      ->image('Image1.jpg');
                        })
                        ->attachment(function (SlackAttachment $attachment) {
                           $attachment->title('Title2')
                                      ->image('Image2.jpg');
                    });
```

But I don't want to pass "attachment" manually, I want to link "attachments" automatically based on the number of loops.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: well using a loop is not enought?

Comment: @Berto99 what's the solution then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$message = new SlackMessage;
foreach($something as $something_else){
      $message->attachment(function (SlackAttachment $attachment) {
          $attachment->title('Title1')
                     ->image('Image1.jpg');
      })
 }
 return $message
```